# why innerTEXT doesn't work with nodes?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to `getElementsByTagName("title")` then alert its values

it tried to use `innerText` it return nothing

Example:

```
<script>
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
    {
      titles = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("title");
      for(i=0; i < titles.length; i++)
      {
    alert(titles[i].innerText);
      }
    }

  }
  req.open("GET","webapp/data",true);
  req.send();
</script>
```

it only works when i use innerHTML but i don't understand why !

Example:

```
<script>
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
    {
      titles = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("title");
      for(i=0; i < titles.length; i++)
      {
    alert(titles[i].innerHTML);
      }
    }

  }
  req.open("GET","webapp/data",true);
  req.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Why not convert the xml to JSON? That way you can access the values more naturally than using the DOM api

Comment: Did really none of these questions help you? [`[javascript] innerText`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+innerText) You searched, right?

Comment: @FelixKling i searched but the problem i don't know how innerHTML gives the value same as textContent

Comment: Right, information like this can be better found in documentation anyway: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML. Reading the MDN documentation about `innerHTML` and `textContent` / `innerText` should teach you what each of those properties return and then you can compare and determine whether it's the same or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`innerText` is the "ancient Internet Explorer" way of doing it.

The correct name is `textContent`.

Comment: it works ! but innerHTML shouldn't work right ? only textContent should work to print the value

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the browser, go with `textContent`

```
titles[i].textContent || titles[i].innerText
```

using `innerText` only as an eventual fallback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

`textContent` is more appropriate way for all browsers and since IE9

`Element.innerHTML` is a reliable cross-browser way to get all HTML content String of an element. The difference from `textContent` is in that `innerHTML` will retrieve the complete HTML structure into a string, while `Node.textContent` will retrieve nodes type 3 (context text) from an element (and it's children).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType